# bash exporting variable which is output of a command, to command fails, unclear why

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to run a freeipa command to modify a user attribute, by storing the result of a command in a variable, before passing it to the command. I hope to be able to script this.
It fails and I dont know why, or how best to do this.
Running the command manually works, but
Here are a few variations I have tried, and the results:

```
    new_date="'$(date +"%F %T" -d "+90 days")Z'"; echo $new_date; ipa user-mod username --password-expiration=$(echo $new_date)
'2023-07-24 07:47:46Z'
ipa: ERROR: command 'user_mod' takes at most 1 argument


export new_date="'$(date +"%F %T" -d "+90 days")Z'"; echo "${new_date}"; ipa user-mod username --password-expiration="${new_date}"
'2023-07-24 07:52:14Z'
ipa: ERROR: invalid 'password_expiration': does not match any of accepted formats: %Y%m%d%H%M%SZ, %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ, %Y-%m-%dT%H:%MZ, %Y-%m-%dZ, %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%SZ, %Y-%m-%d %H:%MZ
```

Please what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried just `--password-expiration=$new_date`?

Comment: Yes, it fails like the others with ``ipa: ERROR: command 'user_mod' takes at most 1 argument``. I cant tell why these are being rejected.

Comment: Ah - your value has a space, so your second attempt is valid (i.e. `--password-expiration="${new_date}"` )... but the second attempt includes single quotes around the value, so doesn't match the patterns.  replace `new_date="'$(date +"%F %T" -d "+90 days")Z'"` with `new_date="$(date +"%F %T" -d "+90 days")Z"`

Comment: You are over-quoting the variable.
Please try: `new_date="$(date +"%F %T" -d "+90 days")Z";
ipa user-mod username --password-expiration="$new_date"`.

Comment: The first attempt is plainly a [useless use of `echo`](https://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#echo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have examined the validity of the command line or the variable
by using `echo` command. But the `echo` command sometimes fools our eyes
because the printed string may differ from the arguments which are
actually fed to the command.
Instead define a tiny function to test the arguments like:

```
check_args() {
    for ((i=1; i<=$#; i++)); do
        printf "[%d] %s\n" "$i" "${!i}"
    done
}
```

Then case 1:

```
new_date="'$(date +"%F %T" -d "+90 days")Z'"
check_args user-mod username --password-expiration=$(echo $new_date)
```

Result:

```
[1] user-mod
[2] username
[3] --password-expiration='2023-07-24
[4] 18:00:28Z'
```

You'll see the last argument is broken due to the whitespace in between.

Case 2:

```
new_date="'$(date +"%F %T" -d "+90 days")Z'"
check_args user-mod username --password-expiration="${new_date}"
```

Result:

```
[1] user-mod
[2] username
[3] --password-expiration='2023-07-24 18:00:28Z'
```

The date string is enclosed by extra quotes.